# Can't open JNLP after changing to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, jnlp

I have a problem where I can't open up .jnlp files. I see the `java web start` is running in the task manager but nothing appears. I had tried to reinstall java clear temp appdata software disruption and cache and turned off firewall and antivirus but that didn't solved it.

I also tried to run it on another Windows 10 machine and there it would run perfectly.
Does anyone know how I might be able to fix it?

My Java version is 8 update 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it was the antivirus even after i turned it off it blocked the jnlp

and also it had been downgraded to a (free version) after the upgradeing to win 10
but after I reinstalled avast to the protection suit it worked again

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767838/5948 where this was an issue that actually got fixed in a later build of the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue with an associate at my company. The problem was that the .jnlp application was only trying to open in IE instead of the Javaws aplication.

What I did was right click on the file > Open with > Browse > C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\javaws

I also marked a check by the box that said set this as default app. The issue no longer affects us

Answer (score 0):

locate the .jnlp file.  right click and select "open with"    ..then browse to a java program that will open it.  I had this problem with marketcaster.jnlp with different browsers and this corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem opening a jnlp file, no matter what, trying to associate it with the Java Web Service exe javaws.exe, but it just would not associate and would not be run. I read throughout forums and all, and in the end from old DOS.exe files that I have used, somehow I did that and a miracle, it worked, I simply dragged the saved jnlp file and dropped it onto the javaws.exe, and it was executed. wanted to share this...

Answer (score 0):

JRE 32 bit was causing issue for me . I uninstalled it and installed 64 bit JRE , JNLP files opened on all browsers. I think the browser n JRE must be both same 32 bit or 64 bit. Mismatch leads to this issue, not sure though.